# Discord.py Guilds Command Showing As "None"

Tags: discord.py

`

```
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def ownguilds(ctx):
      for guild in client.guilds:
        embed=discord.Embed(title=str(guild))
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=guild.icon_url)
        embed.add_field(name="Members:", value=guild.member_count, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Owner:", value=guild.owner, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="ID:", value=guild.id, inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

`

This is a guild command, but every time I use it, the owner section displays as "None"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup your intents like this and make sure you enable server members intent on discord developer portal.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.​guilds​ ​=​ ​True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

[image: developer portal]